# Missing file or plugin on freshly installed Cloud9 ide?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, cloud9-ide

I'm currently trying to set up cloud9 on my debian server for node.js development. I followed some simple steps as described below, but there seems to be missing something and I would like to know how this can be resolved in the best way. Of course, I could start looking for the missing file on the web and put it there, but I think that's not the way to go.

What I did is this:

1. ssh'ed into my Debian server into my home folder
2. `sudo git clone https://github.com/c9/core.git sdk` (completed succesfully)
3. `cd sdk`
4. `sudo ./scripts/install-sdk.sh`

The installation finishes like this:

```
Success!
run 'node server.js -p 8080 -a :' to launch Cloud9
```

When I then start up the IDE with this command:

```
node server.js -p 1234 -l 0.0.0.0 -a rob:mypass -w /home/rob/myproject/
```

...everything looks good:

```
Starting standalone
Connect server listening at http://x.x.x.x:1234
Using basic authentication
CDN: version standalone initialized /home/rob/sdk/build
Started '/home/rob/sdk/configs/standalone' with config 'standalone'!
Cloud9 is up and running
```

and I can *basically* reach the IDE from my local browser. The problem is that it stops on the welcome screen with this loading indicator in the middle right under the cloud9 logo. The JS console shows a missing file (I've replaced my real URL):

```
http://myserver.de:1234/static/plugins/c9.ide.collab/notifications/bubble.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I then looked into the folder `/home/rob/sdk/plugins/c9.ide.collab/`, but it is empty.

What am I missing? Do I need to install something with npm or do I have to change the package.json file somehow? I'd really appreciate some help because I think wildly modifying and copying in files won't make things better.

Comment: Is it possible that your network is preventing installation of any of the packages required? You might have a look at https://github.com/c9/core/issues/311

Comment: No. Meanwhile I got the IDE up and running at last by manually cloning the plugin into the sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit:** It turns out it was "bug in the script updating references [of some plugins]". Details: https://github.com/c9/core/pull/365

—Cheers!

*Original answer:*
I think think the `c9.ide.collab` plugin's refspec is wrong here: https://github.com/z3cka/core/commit/5f45ea38f422160a0030c5ef8d1efb19231bc78c#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2

I changed it back to `#54aa1cbee0`, ran the `install-sdk.sh` and it grabbed the latest version of the collab plugin. While prepping a PR, I just found 3 more plugins with bad refspecs

- `c9.ide.language`
- `c9.ide.language.javascript.eslint`
- `c9.ide.run.debug`

I'm currently working on a fix for the rest of these.

Comment: I filed an issue: https://github.com/c9/core/issues/364 and submitted a pull request: https://github.com/c9/core/pull/365 _(we'll see how this goes)_

Comment: Thank you! I was "hoping" for something like this. I'm just starting with node and I'd rather have a stable reproducable error than a mysterious one that only occurs on my system ;)

Comment: @Robert awesome! If you are into Docker I have an automated c9 build for exactly this. Check it out at: https://hub.docker.com/r/z3cka/c9/ you can run it locally or in ther cloud, or whatever. It's build on debian w/ nvm included.